# Google Play refund a purchase?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

On Google Play, I ordered an app with my Discover Gift Card, and I refunded it within 15 minutes. According to my Card balance, I have not been refunded yet. How will I know when I will get refunded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you get an email from Google Play that a refund was made? If yes, you should be all right.

Sometimes, it takes time before refunds (or anything) shows up on PayPal or your credit card statement. Try again in a few days.

Comment: Credit card refunds can take up to ten working days. As you say, Google should email pretty much on the spot to conform refund.